# UPDATED: redirect url pass parameter from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle11g

I'm would like to do a 2 step process without the user knowing. Right now when the user click on the link from another page.

1. URL redirect to run some JavaScript function that updates the database.
2. Then pass the variable to view a document.

User clicks on this link from another page

Here is some of code in the JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function(){
 var auditObject ="";
 var audit_rec = {};
 var redirLink = "";

 if(document.URL.indexOf('?1w') > -1 {
   redirLink = "https://www.wikipedia.org/";
   auditObject = redirLink;
   audit_rec.action = "OPEN";
   audit_rec.object = auditObject; 
   audit_rec.object_type = "WINDOW";
   audit_rec.status = "Y";
   window.open(redirLink);
   } else {
   audit_rec.target = /MyServlet;
   audit_rec.action = "OPEN";
   audit_rec.object = TESTSITE; 
   audit_rec.object_type = "WINDOW";
   audit_rec.status = "Y";
  }

function audit(audit_rec) {
   var strObject = audit_rec.object;
   strObject = strObject.toLowerCase();
   var strCategory = "";
   if (strObject.indexOf("wiki") > -1) {
      strCategory = "Wiki";
   } else if strObject.indexOf("test") > -1) {
     strCategory = "TEST Home Page";
   }

 //Send jQuery AJAX request to audit the user event.
   $.post(audit_rec.target, {
           ACTION_DATE : String(Date.now()),
      DOMAIN : "TESTSITE",
      ACTION : audit_rec.action,
      OBJECT : audit_rec.object,
      OBJECT_TYPE : audit_rec.object_type,
      STATUS : audit_rec.status
  }); 
 }
 //TEST initial page load.
 audit(audit_rec);
}
</script>
```

Can someone help?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give your link a class or ID such as

```
<a id="doclink" href="http://website.com/docviewer.html?docId=ABC%2Fguide%3A%2F%2F'||i.guide||'">'||i.docno||'</a>
```

then use javascript to intercept it and run your ajax script to update the database. Here's how you'd do it in jQuery:

```
$('#doclink').click(function(e) {
    var linkToFollow = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    yourAjaxFunction(parameters, function() {
        location.href = linkToFollow;
    });
});
```

where the function containing the redirect is a callback function after your ajax script completes. This stops the link from being followed until you've run your ajax script.

Comment: Forgot to mention the link is coming from Outlook email.  So I have to try it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

if your question is to hide the parameters Here is the Answer
you just use input type as hidden the code like this

['||i.docno||'](http://website.com/docviewer.html?docId=ABC%2Fguide%3A%2F%2F%27||i.guide||%27)

Comment: no i'm not trying to hide the parameters. i'm going to try what andrew suggested.  i need to pass parameters to the javascript file via url redirect, run the script in the file that is updating the database, then take the user to the document.  right now it is just taking the user to the document.  Hope this helps.